# How can I inject a JSF bean into another JSF bean in Java 5?

Tags: java, jsf

In Java 6 I would write the following code to access an application scoped bean from a request scoped bean:

Application scoped bean:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Bean1
{
  ...
}
```

Request scoped bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Bean2
{
  @Inject
  private Bean1 bean1;
}
```

How can I accomplish this in Java 5 using JSF which doesn't have these annotations?

Comment: The @Inject annotation does not exist in Java 5. Please read my question more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by configuring Bean1 as a managed-property in my faces-config.xml:

```
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>bean2</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mypackage.Bean2</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>bean1</property-name>
      <property-class>mypackage.Bean1</property-class>
      <value>#{bean1}</value>
    </managed-property>
  </managed-bean>
```

Then I added a set accessor method in my Bean2 class:

```
public class Bean2
{
  private Bean1 bean1 = null;

  public void setBean1(Bean1 b) { this.bean1 = b; }
}
```

The key is that the bean1 property will not be available until after injection so it must not be referenced in Bean2's constructor.